# How to add border bottom on hover effect?

Tags: html, css

How to add border bottom on hover effect as in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm4MQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add **:hover** for your **button** like this:

```css
button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #d94346;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

/* Add hover effect */
button:hover {
    border-bottom: #bb262a 6px solid;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this result what you were expecting for ?
A `box-shadow`would be more appropriate in my opinion.

EDIT: Comparing to the other answers I see, this way the button text won't move. 2 options.

```css
button {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px 250px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #d84446;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 0px #bb262a;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should do it in the other order

```
button:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #bb262a;
}
```

Comment: `other order` other from what? And why was that preferable?

Comment: i meant to say the person on top wrote the border-bottom effect in the wrong order, so you you can do this